# Adapt code so it outputs to the cell as a string

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, search

I have the below code - it's working but it outputs to the console. I'm trying to get it to change the array in to a text string and then output that string to the spreadsheet. I've tried 'return' and other methods but my knowledge of this scripting language is limited.

```
function findInAllSheets(){
  const text = "robert"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const textFinder = ss.createTextFinder(text)
  const allOccurrences = textFinder.findAll();
  const locationList = allOccurrences.map(item => {
    return {sheet:item.getSheet().getName(), cell: item.getA1Notation()}
  })
  console.log(locationList)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you stated that you preferred a `single cell` to be the output rather than filling rows and columns, how about trying the following alternative approach using a **custom function**:

```
function findInAllSheets(){
  const text = "robert"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const textFinder = ss.createTextFinder(text)
  const allOccurrences = textFinder.findAll();

  const locationList = allOccurrences.map(item => {
    return {sheet:item.getSheet().getName(), cell: item.getA1Notation()}
  })
  //console.log(locationList.map(object => object.cell))
  //return[[locationList.map(object => object.cell).join()]] //returns the A1 notation of the specific text

//If you want the sheet name to be included as you have mentioned
  var a = locationList.map(object => object.sheet + ">" + object.cell).join()
  console.log(a)

  return[[locationList.map(object => object.sheet + ">" + object.cell).join()]]

}
```

Assuming that you may want to output its A1 notation in a single cell regardless of the number of instances the text appears in a sheet.

**result:**

[image]

**Updated Result:**
[image]

Comment: This is great - moving in the right direction. Could the sheet name be returned before each cell reference? So the output is Main>B1,Project 1>B6,Project 4>B7 ?

Comment: Yes, just change the code like this: `var a = locationList.map(object => object.sheet + ">" + object.cell).join()
console.log(a)

  return[[locationList.map(object => object.sheet + ">" + object.cell).join()]]` . Hope this helps, please let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

```
function findInAllSheets(){
  const text = "1"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const tf = ss.createTextFinder(text);
  const list = tf.findAll().map(rg => {
    return [rg.getSheet().getName() + "/" + rg.getA1Notation()]
  })
  list.unshift(["name / Range"])
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(list));
  let sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange(1,1,list.length,list[0].length).setValues(list)
}
```

References:

- [ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping the string output would be in a single cell rather than filling rows and columns - is this easy to do?